# React/Express on Nginx/Ubuntu- React app works, Express gives 521 "bad gateway"

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns, nginx

I'm attempting to run both an Express backend and React frontend from one Ubuntu server through Nginx, with Cloudflare handling SSL and DNS. My goal is to have the backend on [api.nonsensefreerecipes.com](https://api.nonsensefreerecipes.com), and the frontend on [nonsensefreerecipes.com](https://nonsensefreerecipes.com).

The front end works great, the backend never connects (usually 521 error).

My backend is running on port 8000, this is the Nginx file at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/api.nonsensefreerecipes.com`:

```
   server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name api.nonsensefreerecipes.com www.api.nonsensefreerecipes.com;
        return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;

}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/key.pem;

        server_name api.nonsensefreerecipes.com www.api.nonsensefreerecipes.com;
        root /var/www/api.nonsensefreerecipes.com/nnr-dev/backend;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }


}
```

I've made a symbolic link of this config file to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`, of course.

Aside from the port being 8000 instead of 3000, this is the exact same config file that works perfectly for the React app. I also tried `listen 8000` and `listen 8443` with no luck.

The Cloudflare SSL covers the domain and the subdomain, and the certificate is valid on both. api.nonsensefreerecipes.com is secure, it just never connects.

The Express server lives at `/var/www/api.nonsensefreerecipes.com/nnr-dev/backend`, any variation of starting the server (i.e. `npm start` etc) runs the server (`starting server..js... MongoDB Connected`, etc) on the Ubuntu console, and I've verified this server runs great anywhere else. It's definitely a Nginx problem.

Last note- the IP address for the server is 147.190.62.177 . Cloudflare is pushing both api.non... and non... to that IP address. From my limited understanding, adding :8000 to this should pull up the Express server, but that's not working either.

I really appreciate any help, this is my first time trying to do this and I've been stuck for a few days now.

Comment: A bit late now, but this question would have perhaps received a better response on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 1):

HTTP status code 521 returned by Cloudflare indicates that it could not connect to 147.190.62.177 port 443.
The first thing that I would check is if the firewall on the Ubuntu server is configured to accept connections from [Cloudflare IPs](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/). By default, Ubuntu comes with UFW, so the command to check for rules is this:

```
sudo ufw status verbose
```

To add INPUT rules to UFW, use these commands for each Clousflare address (`CF_IP_ADDRESS_N`):

```
sudo ufw allow from CF_IP_ADDRESS_N to any port 80 proto tcp
sudo ufw allow from CF_IP_ADDRESS_N to any port 443 proto tcp
```

Please note that there might be one or more firewalls between your Ubuntu server and the internet. Make sure that all are configured to accept connections from CF.

Verify that the Nginx service is running correctly by checking its status:

```
systemctl status nginx
```

Verify that Nginx was able to bind to TCP ports 80 and 443:

```
sudo ss -lntp | grep -E ":(80|443)\s"
```

Then verify that Express is bound to port TCP 8000:

```
sudo ss -lntp | grep -E ":8000\s"
```

Verify that Nginx responds with a valid HTTP response when accessing the site directly from the Ubuntu server:

```
curl -Ik -H "Host: api.nonsensefreerecipes.com" https://127.0.0.1/
```

Verify that Express responds with a valid HTTP response when accessing the site directly from the Ubuntu server:

```
curl -I http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

These tips should be a good starting point.